# How to render react class component with React HashRouter and Apollo client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, apollo-client, react-class-based-component

I am working at a project in which I must use only React class components and I am fetching data from an Apollo server.
The problem is that in Chrome is rendering only the Navbar.jsx. When I am navigating on one of the links nothing is on the screen. Also there is not any error in the console. 
Could somebody help me?
Thanks!
This is Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: ' http://localhost:4000/',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter >
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>      
    <App />    
    </ApolloProvider>
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Here is App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import { Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Bikes from './Pages/Bikes';
import Books from './Pages/Books';
import { client } from './index';
import {GET_QUERY} from './GraphQl/Queries'

class App extends Component {
  state={
    currencies: [],
  }
  componentDidMount = async ()=>{
    const response = await client.query({
      query:GET_QUERY
    })
    this.setState({
      currencies:response.data.currencies
    })    
  }
  
  render() {
    return (   
      <div className="App">        
          <Navbar currencies={this.state.currencies}/>          
          <Switch>            
            <Route exact path="/bikes" component={Bikes} />
            <Route exact path="/books" component={Books} />;            
          </Switch>      
      </div>      
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Here is Navbar.jsx :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`

`;

class Navbar extends Component {         
    render() {    
        return (
            <nav>
                <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <StyledLink to="/bikes" replace>Bikes</StyledLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <StyledLink to="/books" replace>Books</StyledLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>               
           </nav>
        )
    }
}
export default withRouter(Navbar)
```

and one of the pages, Bikes.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { client } from '../index'
import { GET_QUERY } from '../GraphQl/Queries'
import { CATEGORY_VAR } from '../GraphQl/Variables'

class Bikes extends Component {
    state={
        bikesArt: []
    }
    componentDidMount = async ()=>{
        const response = await client.query({
            query: GET_QUERY,
            variables: CATEGORY_VAR
        })
        this.setState({
            bikesArt:response.data.category.products
        })
    }    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Bikes</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Bikes
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. It was the CSS. The navbar was covering the only `<h2>` tag from the page